# Laravel Validation - custom rule, custom error message

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I'm extending the Laravel Validation rules to create a rule for "between two user-supplied fields" - the `between` rule only handles "between two values".

```
Validator::extend('between_fields', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $data = $validator->getData();

    $min = array_get( $data, $parameters[0], $parameters[0] );
    $max = array_get( $data, $parameters[1], $parameters[1] );

    return $value >= $min && $value <= $max;
});
```

This works fine, but I'd then like to define an error message which uses the numeric values. I've set up a message like this:

```
'between_fields' => ':attribute must be between :min and :max.',
```

...which is how the existing `between` rule works, but the `:min` and `:max` don't get replaced with anything.

How do I pass the values for those from the Validator extension through to the message handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to that with the `Validator::replacer()`

`Validator::replacer('between_fields', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters){
    return str_replace(...); //replace placeholders with the values you want
});`

Comment: Ahh, I knew I must be missing something :) Turns out that *is* in the docs, it's just not named in an obvious way haha. Thanks a lot. I'll accept the answer shortly, once I've jumped back on to that project and tested it